# Why does a previously working Xcode project hang up in Xcode 7 when presenting a new UITableviewController Subclass?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

Moving my project over to Xcode 7 caused the project to hang in 2 places both where a new UITableViewController subclass should have been presented. It seems to be a bug in Xcode 7 and is also present in 7.01, The project worked fine in Xcode 6.4.

This bug doesn't throw an exception, things just seem too hang.

Wading thru the code line by line it became clear that in both cases there was an issue returning a UITableViewCell with UITextView's upon the tableviewCell.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a blog. If you think this info is helpful to others, post it properly. Post an actual question above. Then post an actual answer below.

Comment: As I said, simply fix your post so it consists of an actual question and a separate, proper answer and then it will be fine. Lots of people make such question/self-answer posts. That fine. But as you have it now, it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

On the debugger navigator  you might see it showing a reference to `[NSLocalizableString length]` on your thread. My codes does not explicitly call `NSLocalizableString` but it seems like something that a textView might be dealing with.

The solution is simple - remove any initial text from the UITextview in interface builder, doing a product->clean and running the code again.

This resolves the issue and the expected table views are presented as they were previously in using Xcode 6.4

Hope this saves someone else several hours of banging their head against a wall.

Right, off to file a radar with Apple.

Comment: Yes. I am also facing the same problem. When i removed the initial text from UITextView in Storyboard it is working fine.