# Firebase function freezes app in xcode7, but works in xcode6.4

Tags: ios, autolayout, firebase, swift2, xcode7

For some reason this code works perfectly in xcode6.4, but when switching to xcode7 it freezes the app.

What I am trying to do is pull the post information on a user's feed and display it on a tableview. I am able to pull the information from Firebase, but the app freezes before it displays on the tableview.

EDIT: The tableview works when I do not have any constraints or autolayout. It seems to not work when I try to have dynamic cell heights.

```
func getRadarData() {
    let url = "https://(insert appname).firebaseio.com/users/" + currentUser + "/postsReceived/"
    let targetRef = Firebase(url: url)

    targetRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        print("child")

        if let found = self.posts.map({ $0.key }).indexOf(snapshot.key) {
            let obj = self.posts[found]
            print(obj)
            print(found)
            self.posts.removeAtIndex(found)
        }

        let postsUrl = "https://(insert appname).firebaseio.com/posts/" + snapshot.key
        let postsRef = Firebase(url: postsUrl)
        var updatedAt = snapshot.value["updatedAt"] as? NSTimeInterval
        var endAt = snapshot.value["endAt"] as? NSTimeInterval

        if updatedAt == nil {
            updatedAt = 0
        }

        if endAt == nil {
            endAt = 0
        }

        postsRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if let key = snapshot.key
            {if let content = snapshot.value["content"] as? String {
                if let creator = snapshot.value["creator"] as? String {
                    if let createdAt = snapshot.value["createdAt"] as? NSTimeInterval {
                                let userurl = "https://(insert appname).firebaseio.com/users/" + (creator)
                                let userRef = Firebase(url: userurl)
                                userRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                                    if let username = snapshot.value["username"] as? String {
                                        let updatedDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (updatedAt!/1000))
                                        let createdDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (createdAt/1000))
                                        let endedDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (endAt!))

                                        let post = Post(content: content, creator: creator, key: key, createdAt: updatedDate, name: username, joined: true, messageCount: 0, endAt: endedDate)

                                        self.posts.append(post)

                                        // Sort posts in descending order
                                        self.posts.sortInPlace({ $0.createdAt.compare($1.createdAt) == .OrderedDescending })
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                                    }
                                })

                    }
                }
                }

            }
        })
    })
}
```

Here is my code for my tableview where I used autolayout on the textView and nameLabel

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: RadarTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("radarCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RadarTableViewCell

    let creator: (String) = posts[indexPath.row].creator
    let key = posts[indexPath.row].key

    let radarContent: (AnyObject) = posts[indexPath.row].content
    cell.textView.selectable = false
    cell.textView.text = radarContent as? String
    cell.textView.userInteractionEnabled = false

    cell.textView.selectable = true

    let radarCreator: (AnyObject) = posts[indexPath.row].name

    cell.nameLabel.text = radarCreator as? String

    return cell
```

Comment: Hey Brian, sorry to hear this. Do you mind cleaning up this example a little (or posting the full standalone code of this), since I'm having a little trouble getting this to "just work" out of the box, and I'm worried that if I start ripping things out that will change the behavior. Also, is this XCode 7.1 beta, or 7.0? Can you add breakpoints or see where it's freezing (maybe post comparisons of expected behavior in XCode 6.4 and XCode 7 by showing what is printing)?

Comment: I added my code for my tableview. I am also using xcode 7.0. I am able to grab the information from firebase, but the app freezes before it displays on the tableView

Comment: Also Firebase is working every other instance I use it. Just seems to be a problem with this particular function and tableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had initial text in my textView. I deleted it on my Storyboard and my app works now.

Found the solution here: [Why does a previously working Xcode project hang up in Xcode 7 when presenting a new UITableviewController Subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870212/why-does-a-previously-working-xcode-project-hang-up-in-xcode-7-when-presenting-a)